# who owns the copyright to someone giving a speech

Tags: copyright

My question is about video recordings. Who owns the right to a video recording? Is it the person recording or the person being recorded?

Comment: See: [Who owns the copyright when video recording lectures at a conference (with permission)?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7652/who-owns-the-copyright-when-video-recording-lectures-at-a-conference-with-permi)

Comment: If someone writes a speech, and delivers a speech, that is a creative work. It is copyrighted as soon as it is fixed in a tangible medium, such as notes that the speaker used in order to deliver the speech. If someone records that speech by simply pointing a camera at the speaker and recording it, then that act is arguably a derivative work of the speaker's speech and would need permission from the speaker.